# ReactNative onEndReached triggers when return to the page with scroll at bottom already triggering endless GQL fetchMore loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, mobile, frontend

so I have a `flatList` rendering a bunch of items, make use of `onEndReached` to trigger a GQL hook and a `fetchMore` function. When clicking an item at the bottom, where it triggers this, navigating to a new page (on top of stack), clicking back (popping page off stack) and back to results page with the list, it will trigger the `onEndReached` without a scroll not recognising there is more loaded below it, endlessly until no more data left.